# RSS Feed Manually Parse Image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rss

Using the feedparser module on python I was able to parse the title, description, link, and date from this XML file: https://www.espn.com/espn/rss/nba/news

In the XML file there is most definitely an image for each article but feedparser does not recognize this. The keys that it displays are the following:

```
dict_keys(['title', 'title_detail', 'summary', 'summary_detail', 'links', 'link', 'published', 'published_parsed', 'id', 'guidislink'])
```

Is there a way to manually parse the images? This is my current script:

```
url = 'https://www.espn.com/espn/rss/' + league + '/news'
    
parser = feedparser.parse(url)

newsInfo = []

for entry in parser.entries:
        newEntry = {
            'title': entry.title,
            'description': entry.description,
            'link': entry.link,
            'date': entry.published_parsed,
            'displayDate': entry.published
        }
        newsInfo.append(newEntry)
return newsInfo
```

I would like to keep the images with the corresponding article.

Comment: I am having the same issue and unable to find a solution. I have asked the feedparser developer for input but no reply as yet (https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/issues/216). Did you come up with some answer?

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen Check my answer. This will work if the image is a jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

```
def newsParse(league):
    url = 'https://www.espn.com/espn/rss/' + league + '/news'

    def seperate_description_and_image(s):
        if '\n' in s:
            return s.rsplit('\n', 1)
        else:
            return [s, ""]

    # Need access to feed before parsing
    # parser = feedparser.parse(url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    # error check response.status_code here...

    # join sub-element <description> and unknown sub-element <image> 
    # in RSS 2.0 <item> and seperate with \n
    raw = response.text
    raw = raw.replace("</description><image>", "\n")
    raw = raw.replace(".jpg]]></image>", ".jpg]]>\n</description>")
    
    # now parse
    parser = feedparser.parse(raw)

    newsInfo = []
    for entry in parser.entries:
        try:
            newEntry = {
            'title': entry.title,
            'description': seperate_description_and_image(entry.description)[0],
            'image': seperate_description_and_image(entry.description)[1],
            'link': entry.link,
            'date': entry.published_parsed,
            'displayDate': entry.published
            }
            newsInfo.append(newEntry)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
    
    return newsInfo
```

Comment: that is a great help. Building on your example I have generalized the solution a little but i the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from @RudyGoburt, I have a more generalized solution. As `feedparser` does not handle an `<image> ... </image>` inside the `<item>` fields, I parse the raw html and extract the url inside the image tag and place it inside an `<enclosure>` tag. Feedparser can handle enclosures so the image url is being extracted.

Solution below has some checks to be able to handle various other rss feeds as well. Note that images can also be extracted from `media_content` if available.

```
import requests
import re
import time
import feedparser
from pprint import pprint


def generalised_parse(url):
    raw = ''
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)

        if response and response.status_code == 200:
            raw = response.text

        else:
            pass

    except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.MissingSchema):
        pass

    # if raw <item>'s have a '<image> ... </image>' pattern extract the image url and
    # put this image url in an <enclosure /> tag which can be handled by feedparser
    raw = re.sub(r'(<item>.*?)<image>.*?(http.*?jpg|png|gif).*?</image>(.*?</item>)',
                 r'\1<enclosure url="\2" />\3', raw)
    
    # some url give an empty raw string, in that case parse with the url instead of 
    # the raw string
    if raw:
        parser = feedparser.parse(raw)

    else:
        parser = feedparser.parse(url)

    newsInfo = []
    for entry in parser.entries:
        # looks like entry has always an attribute enclosures, although maybe an 
        # empty list
        if entry.enclosures:
            enclosure_href = entry.enclosures[0]['href']
        
        else:
            enclosure_href = ''

        # check if there is media_content
        try:
            media_url = entry.media_content[0]['url']
        
        except AttributeError:
            media_url = ''

        # some entry have no attribute published, in that case check for attribute
        # updated, if that does not exist give default date of 1970-1-1
        try: 
            published = entry.published
            published_parsed = entry.updated_parsed
        
        except AttributeError:
            published = entry.get('updated', '1970-01-01')
            published_parsed = entry.get('updated_parsed', 
                time.struct_time((1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)))

        # use get method so that in case attribute does not exist we can give a default
        # value
        newEntry = {
            'title': entry.get('title', ''),
            'description': entry.get('summary', ''),
            'link': entry.get('link', ''),
            'enclosure' : enclosure_href,
            'media': media_url,
            'date': published_parsed,
            'displayDate': published,
        }
        newsInfo.append(newEntry)
    
    return newsInfo


def main():
    # you can try out with various rss feeds
    url_espn_rpm = 'https://www.espn.com/espn/rss/rpm/news'
    url_espn_pl = 'http://www.espnfc.com/english-premier-league/23/rss'
    url_cnn = 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss'
    url_reddit = 'http://www.reddit.com/.rss'
    url_bbc = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml'

    news_info = generalised_parse(url_espn_pl)
    pprint(news_info)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```